# Append Cut&Delete Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some problems with my vba codes.

I have some data in columns 'A' to 'D'. On Column 'F' I coppied column 'B' and seperate it by Text To Colums function. So now I have some data from columns 'F' to maximum column 'I'. But more than a half cells are still empty. I want to write a loop that will go through each cell and if it's not empty cut that cell and append it to column 'B' under the data. I had write some code here but it doesn't work like I want it to. What's wrong here, I would be pleased for any suggestion.

```
Dim DługośćTabeli As Integer
DługośćTabeli = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row

Dim OstatniWiersz As Integer
For OstatniWiersz = DługośćTabeli To 1 Step -1
    If Not Cells(OstatniWiersz, 10) = "" Then
        Range("I" & OstatniWiersz).Cut Range("B" & (OstatniWiersz + 1000))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: As `OstatniWiersz` goes down in your loop, `Range("B" & (OstatniWiersz + 1000)` is going up the column - e.g it starts in B1010 and then B1009 etc - which I assume you don't want.

Comment: Sure, I have changed "Range("B" & (OstatniWiersz + 1000)" to "Range("B" & (DługośćTabeli + 1000) but it still doesn't work. I just want to append that to the end of table but don't know how to I try to append that far more and after that delete empty rows.

Comment: Why are you adding 1000? If you use `DługośćTabeli` you need to increment that otherwise you will be overwriting.